# What does ∫(/a) mean?

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

What does ∫(/a) **mean?** 
For example: ∫(/a) = ∫(/a)(/a) = 1/a * ∫(p)(p) = 1/a

From what I understand, the delta function - **(/a)**  is being compressed by a scaling factor **a**. Thus the area under the curve is "shrunk" by **a**.

What I don't understand is why do we need to "(/a)" ? I've only understood d(t) as "a very small increment of the unit".

Thanks for your time. I hope my question was specific enough.

Comment: Please provide some context.  Did you actually see that set of equations some place?  Where?  Surely $d\left(\frac ta\right)$ is $\frac {dt}a$ which is not consistent with what you wrote.

Comment: The thing you've written after "For example" is not correct in any context I have seen.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. you (all) are indeed correct. (/) is / is definitely not consistent. I don't know if I should edit the post itself but it should be ∫(a) = ∫(a)(a)*1/a = 1/a * ∫(p)(p) = 1/a. Which makes much more sense after reading the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't agree at all that ∫(/a) = ∫(/a)(/a), or with the rest of your computation for that matter.

But I can explain what the d(t/a) means. It means that your small increments of time are weighed down by how much the function $t\mapsto t/a$ varies in each of them.

In general, you can replace $g'(t)dt$ by $d(g(t))$ in an integral, for any function $g$. You usually do that when you are preparing a change of variables.

Indeed if you can write the integrand as a function of $g(t)$ too, then you take your new variable $p$ to represent $g(t)$.

For instance (assume $a>0$ for clarity)

$$\int \delta(t/a) dt = a \int \delta(t/a) \dfrac 1a dt =  a\int \delta(t/a) d (t/a) = a\int \delta(p) dp = a.$$

In the first equality I introduced a $1/a$ term by mutiplicating by $a$. In the second one I recognized that $\dfrac 1a$ is the derivative of $t/a$. In the third one I performed the change of variables $p=1/a$.

Comment: I believe $|a|$ is needed here because delta function is even

Comment: You're right but it has nothing to do with $\delta$ being even. I'll just edit to assume $a>0$ for clarity

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have corrected myself above in the comments. The answer you gave definitely cleared up my confusion. Thank you.

Comment: Splendid then! Glad to help.